# Given $f(ax)=\log_a (x)$, find $f(x)$.

Tags: functions

I don’t know how to work through this question.

If $ax=c$, then couldn’t different factors of $c$ form different answers?

Comment: Is $a$ fixed or arbitrary? I realized in my previous comment I assumed it was arbitrary but that seems wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $x \rightarrow x/a$ to get

$$f(x) = \log_a(x/a) = \log_a(x)-1$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** For any $a>0$ with $a \neq 1$, $f(a) = f(a \cdot 1) = \log_a(1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $$f(ax) = \log_a (x) = \frac{ \log(x) }{ \log(a) }$$
You can try with
$$f(x) = \frac{ \log(x) - \log(a) }{ \log(a) }$$